# Arrange list in reverse_array within {foreach}

Tags: php, smarty

I am using {foreach} within smarty like this

```
{foreach key=num item=reply from=$replies}
//something goes here.
{/foreach}
```

Currently I am getting replies arranged like...

Older --> Old --> New --> Newer

I want to arrange them in this order

Newer --> New --> Old --> Older

How to achieve this ?

**Thanks**

**Solved**

Thanks  to ts for this

```
from=$replies|@array_reverse
```

& Required following smarty plugin

modifier.reverse_array.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Smarty plugin
 * @package Smarty
 * @subpackage plugins
 */


/**
 * Smarty reverse_array modifier plugin
 *
 * Type:     modifier<br>
 * Name:     reverse_array<br>
 * Purpose:  reverse arrays
 * @author   Noel McGran 
 * @param array
 * @return array
 */
function smarty_modifier_reverse_array($array)
{
    return array_reverse($array);
}

/* vim: set expandtab: */

?>
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This will solve the problem:

```
from=$replies|@array_reverse
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out [`array_reverse()`](http://php.net/function.array-reverse) ;)

if not, you could simply put data on a new array (or whatever structure you are using) with foreach and [`array_pop()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) then you have it in the other way ;) stack vs queue

Comment: My seccond option probably the best one for you then ;) first use one foreach and put the elements in a new structure following a LIFO then use a new foreach and just print it (or use it, or whatever :P) ;)

Answer (score 0):

If your data is coming from a database simply use an `ORDER BY` clause instead of some hack in your template.

```
SELECT ... FROM ... ORDER BY date DESC
```